# Assigning values to variable of same name in match case causes "Unused variable:" warning

Tags: python, pydev

I have the following Python code:

```
def func(str_param):
    match str_param:
        case some_class.some_str:
            my_var = dict_a
        case some_class.some_str2:
            my_var = dict_b
        case some_class.some_str3:
            my_var = dict_c
        case _:
            raise someError()

    out = some_other_func(my_var)
```

PyDev shows a warning "Unused variable: my_var" for the first two definitions of `my_var` and I can't figure out why. If it's of any help, the `dict_x` are of type dictionary, `str_param` and `some_strx` are of type string.

I have the same match case structure in different places too and I get no warnings there. I wouldn't expect any warnings in my case.
I am programming in Squish IDE 7.1.0 using Python 3.10.

[image: Actual code with warning]

Update: I also initialized the variable before the match case as an empty dictionary, but it still showed the "unused variable" warning, even though I use it as a parameter in my following function `some_other_func(my_var)`.

Comment: You assign the variable but never do anything with it. What's the point? I'll bet the other places use the variable after the match statement is done.

Comment: Also, you assign the result of the function to a variable, but the function has no `return` statement.

Comment: What you probably need is `return my_var` at the end.

Comment: Is the line `out = some_other_func(my_var)` supposed to be indented, so that it is inside the function`func`?

Comment: Please replace the pseudo code you have with the _actual_ code that is shown in your screenshot.

Comment: Or, if you can reproduce the error messages with the minimal code that you provide in text-form, then replace the screenshot with one showing *that*.  Either way, I agree with @TylerH that they should match.  I've voted to reopen, but it probably won't happen without that additional edit. Thanks!